# Finding complexity of heap function

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, heapsort, space-complexity, code-complexity

I am going to use the following code for Heap sort (Link: https://github.com/kevin-wayne/algs4/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/Heap.java)

Given the following code:

```
public static void sort(Comparable[] pq) {                     // Complexity: O(NLog N)
    int n = pq.length;                                         // Complexity: O(1)
    for (int k = n/2; k >= 1; k--)                             // Complexity: O(N)
        sink(pq, k, n);                                        // Complexity: O(Log N)
    while (n > 1) {                                            // Complexity: O(N)
        exch(pq, 1, n--);                                      // Complexity: O(1)
        sink(pq, 1, n);                                        // Complexity: O(Log N)
    }
}

private static void sink(Comparable[] pq, int k, int n) {      // Complexity: O(Log N)
    while (2*k <= n) {                                         // Complexity: O(Log N)
        int j = 2*k;                                           // Complexity: O(1)
        if (j < n && less(pq, j, j+1)) j++;                    // Complexity: O(1)
        if (!less(pq, k, j)) break;                            // Complexity: O(1)
        exch(pq, k, j);                                        // Complexity: O(1)
        k = j;                                                 // Complexity: O(1)
    }
}
private static boolean less(Comparable[] pq, int i, int j) {   // Complexity: O(1)
    return pq[i-1].compareTo(pq[j-1]) < 0;                     // Complexity: O(1)
}
private static void exch(Object[] pq, int i, int j) {          // Complexity: O(1)
    Object swap = pq[i-1];                                     // Complexity: O(1)
    pq[i-1] = pq[j-1];                                         // Complexity: O(1)
    pq[j-1] = swap;                                            // Complexity: O(1)
}
```

I wanted to know if my thinking is correct?? I am a bit of a noob in this domain.

Comment: Be careful with the complexity of `sink`: it depends on the value of `k` too, and should be written as `O(log N - log K)`.

Comment: okay..seems good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic looks correct. The sort function is N + N*log(N) which does simplify to N*log(N). Typically you don't do this sort of analysis line by line but instead you just look for every place in the code that involves iteration but this way works.

Comment: so do we always essentially look only on loops which affect most of the complexity?

Comment: Essentially yes.